# Can lag features be applied into test data without label?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, random-forest, forecasting

can lag features be applied into test data without label? I've been wondering. I tried to build random forest model using dataset: training data (with label Y) and testing data (without label Y). The dataset contains datetime column. Label Y is numeric contains revenue value for each column date, district, type.

I try to do feature engineering adding lag feature using PyTimeTK as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pytimetk as tk

df_dates = df.augment_timeseries_signature(date_column = 'date')

df_test_dates = df_test.augment_timeseries_signature(date_column = 'date')

df_with_lags  = df_dates.augment_lags(
        date_column  = 'date',
        value_column = 'Y',
        lags         = [5,6,7,8,9]
    )

lag_columns = [col for col in df_with_lags.columns if 'lag' in col]
```

I have completed the training of a Random Forest Regressor model. However, I am currently facing a challenge in applying lag features to the test data as it lacks corresponding 'Y' labels. Additionally, attempting to predict the test data without the inclusion of lag features results in an error due to a mismatch in feature dimensions.

```
FEATURES = [ 
    'district'
    , 'type'
    , 'date_year'
    , 'date_month'
    , 'date_yweek'
    , 'date_mweek'
    , 'Y_lag_5'
    , 'Y_lag_6'
    , 'Y_lag_7'
    , 'Y_lag_8'
    ]

TARGET = 'Y'

X_train = train[FEATURES]
y_train = train[TARGET]

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=123)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

df_test['Y'] = rf.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

If lagged values are not available for test data you could use model predictions iteratively to create estimated lagged values and use them as input and get results. Just be sure that you understand that using this approach you are not generating model predictions in the same way you did on training and estimating error can increase a lot because it is using an input that already contains some error.

On training: $\hat{y}_t = f(y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, ..., y_{t-k})$

- Get 1-step-ahead error.

On testing:  $\hat{y}_t = f(\hat{y}_{t-1}, \hat{y}_{t-2}, ..., \hat{y}_{t-k})$

- Get k-step-ahead error as you are just using information up to the last training data point.

Comment: To generate model predictions on test data, the test data needs to have the same shape as the training data. Since the training data includes lag features while the test data does not, the predictions contain error.